# Make text responsive according to how tall the tab is

Tags: html, css, responsive

How would I go about having my text be bigger, so my text goes to the bottom of the tab (without a scrollbar showing up or anthing) and when the tab gets smaller, make the font smaller.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: ?;
}
```

```css
div {
  length: according to browser;
}
```

Comment: You can use height : 100vh; for height without showing scrollbar and for font size you can use media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `height: 100vh;` to set height according to screen height, and for font-size you can use `@media queries` to set font size for different screen.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div.box {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #666;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
   padding: 30px;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
  }
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 55px;
  }
}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 65px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="box">
    <h1>Karar Barcha</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vw` for `font-size` if you want to be changed size by resizing of browser:

However, using `vw` for elements such as text means you may want to use `media-queries` for mobile devices to avoid very small text, such as the `<p>` element.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>arman ebrahimi</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Using `vw` values for font-size should is not good practice. Especially with larger `vw` values, the font quickly gets out of control and becomes too small for mobile devices and too large for desktop screens. [uxdesign](https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/how-to-create-truly-fluid-typography-online-efe5dcf58a9c)

Comment: you should mention the inevitable need for `media queries` if you are going to use viewport units as a method of sizing fonts.

Comment: @カメロン Thanks for editing.